# Distance between voxels or pixels to millimeters

Tags: image-processing, graphics, vtk, itk

I have a 3D binary image. Say the resolution is `dx,dy,dz` mm. How can Euclidean distances on the image be converted to distances in mm.

Furhter, If I computed an iso-surface using the marching cubes algorithm. A surface mesh is generated. The Euclidean distance between two mesh vertices - how can this be converted to mm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you have some voxel size in millimetres and this is not necessarily isotropic (i.e. the voxels are not regular cubes).

So if each voxel has dimensions `dx * dy * dz` and you have two voxels at positions `(x1, y1, z1)` and `(x2, y2, z2)`, the you want to find the Euclidean (straight line) distance between these two points in millimetres.

So, first convert each point to get a spatial position (call these `s1` and `s2`)

`s1(x,y,z) = (x1 * dx, y1 * dy, z1 * dz)`, and
`s2(x,y,z) = (x2 * dx, y2 * dy, z2 * dz)`

Then the distance, `d`, between these points in millimetres is then length of the vector, `v`, from `s1` to `s2`

`v(x,y,z) = (s2.x - s1.x, s2.y - s1.y, s2.z - s1.z)`

Distance `d = sqrt(v.x^2 + v.y^2 + v.z^2)` millimetres.

Comment: Thanks for this (it was very useful to know), but my question was more about distance on surfaces in millimeters. The surface is generated from the image using a marching cubes algorithm. Assuming no further triangulations or smoothing is executed.

Comment: @dr_rk well this is a similar issue, you first have to find a path across the surface between the two points (non-trivial) which you can approximate by looking at successive nearest vertices in the desired direction and then accumulate the distances as described above. Whether you generated the mesh using marching cubes or some other algorithm is not relevant.